# Suming a specific TableView column/row in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, sum, row, tableview

I have done this in java where I sum the values of the price column/row. But I am wondering how to do this in JavaFX.

I want to sum everything in column 1 and display it in a `inputField`, I used this to do it in java but how do you do this in JavaFX?

```
tableview.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < tableview.getItems().size(); i++) {
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(tableview.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
}

sumTextField.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

Comment: What kind of object are you displaying in each row of the table? What property is displayed in column 1?

Comment: I only want to display column 1 which has price, so the rows contains int value

Comment: That's not enough information. Perhaps you can show some code with the model class for your table and how the columns are set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have a `TableView<Integer>`, which seems to be what you are saying in the comments, you can just do

```
TableView<Integer> table = ... ;

int total = 0 ;
for (Integer value : table.getItems()) {
    total = total + value;
}
```

or, using a Java 8 approach:

```
int total = table.getItems().stream().summingInt(Integer::intValue);
```

If you have a more standard set up with an actual model class for your table, then you would need to iterate through the items list and call the appropriate get method on each item, then add the result to the total. E.g. something like

```
TableView<Item> table = ...;

int total = 0 ;
for (Item item : table.getItems()) {
    total = total + item.getPrice();
}
```

or, again in Java 8 style

```
int total = table.getItems().stream().summingInt(Item::getPrice);
```

Both of these assume you have an `Item` class with a `getPrice()` method, and the column in question is displaying the `price` property of each item.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void totalCalculation (){

   double TotalPrice = 0.0;
    TotalPrice = Yourtable.getItems().stream().map(
            (item) -> item.getMontant()).reduce(TotalPrice, (accumulator, _item) -> accumulator + _item);

          TexfieldTotal.setText(String.valueOf(TotalPrice));
}
//getMontant is the getter of your column
```

Comment: java naming conventions please