# How to get column totals of TableView with editable columns?

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

I have a table view that shows the time sheets of employees working hours on different projects, from Monday to Friday. The data source is a list of time sheet classes with float properties to each day of the week. I would like to, for instance, show a value that adds all the hours from the Monday column and show a Monday Hours total. I thought it would be easy to do with a little research because, to me, wanting a column total would be common in data driven applications that would use TableViews but I can't seem to find an elegant answer, or really any answer at all. It would be easier if I could just calculate a column total whenever the list of timesheets changed, but I also have to listen for when the column values change/are edited by the user. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640634/suming-a-specific-tableview-column-row-in-javafx) on edit committed?

Comment: I knew that there was a way to grab items in table and choose which properties to add up, but I had trouble figuring out a way to detect when a change was made. I forgot about `onEditCommit { /*add up monday hours, set as new total*/ }`, so thanks for that reminder!

Comment: I am guessing that since the list is observable, you can create a property to bind the column total. My answer does not show that.

Comment: Actually, binding the column totals is a little hard for me, since the table view I'm using actually changes data often and has the option to add and subtract rows, meaning that every time there was a change to the table's list, I'd have to make a new binding and reassign it to the UI component showing the total (unless there's a better way to do this that I don't know about). At that point, it seems like a wasted effort. I'm just going to update a SimpleFloatProperty instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-tornadofx version. In `setOnEditCommit`, update the observable list and sum the column.

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class App extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Label total = new Label("0");

        ObservableList<Time> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        data.add(new Time(0));
        data.add(new Time(3));

        TableView<Time> tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.setItems(data);

        total.setText(Integer.toString(data.stream().mapToInt(Time::getHours).sum()));
        TableColumn<Time, Integer> column1 = new TableColumn("Time");
        column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("hours"));
        column1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public String toString(Integer t)
            {
                return Integer.toString(t);
            }

            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string)
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(string);
            }
        }));
        column1.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Time, Integer> t) -> {
            ((Time) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setHours(t.getNewValue());

            total.setText(Integer.toString(data.stream().mapToInt(Time::getHours).sum()));
        });;

        tableView.getColumns().add(column1);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(tableView, total);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

> Time

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

public class Time
{

    private final IntegerProperty hours = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public Time(int hours)
    {
        this.hours.set(hours);
    }

    public IntegerProperty hoursProperty()
    {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(int hours)
    {
        this.hours.set(hours);
    }

    public Integer getHours()
    {
        return this.hours.getValue();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes `setOnEditCommit` (or `onEditCommit { /* action */ }` for TornadoFX's builder) was what I was looking for! Couldn't remember a good way to detect changes.